# use an alternate for flatmap in javascript

Tags: javascript

Need alternate way for flatmap in javascript lower es5 version for the below mapping.

```js
const b = [{
  "errorname": [{
    "name": "Error 01",
    "desc_1": "Test: 01",
    "desc_2": "Testing"
  }, {
    "name": "Error 03",
    "desc_1": "Test: 03",
    "desc_2": "Testing"
  }],
}, {
  "errorname": [{
    "name": "Error 02",
    "desc_1": "Test: 02",
    "desc_2": "Testing"
  }, {
    "name": "Error 09",
    "desc_1": "Test: 09",
    "desc_2": "Testing"
  } ]
}];

var errorMap = new Map(b
  .flatMap(o => o.errorname)
  .map(({
    name,
    ...e
  }) => [name, e]));



console.log(errorMap)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

trying for es5 with a similar kind of operation. The application is accessed using electron app which doesnot support es9

Comment: You use `Map`, an arrow function and destructuring, in addition to `.flatMap()`. Why is only the last one a problem?

Comment: Why not use a polyfill?

Comment: You can find polyfills for all of the array methods [here](https://github.com/behnammodi/polyfill/blob/master/array.polyfill.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a polyfill or implement your own. It should be like this

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(mapper) {
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    var item = mapper(this[i], i, this);

    if (!Array.isArray(item)) {
      item = [item];
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < item.length; ++j) {
      result.push(item[j]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Then you will be able to call `myArray.flatMap` as you would do normally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. i have added polyfill and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner-outer reduce by nesting the calls. This will work for an ECMAScript version under 5/6.

```js
const b = [{
  "errorname": [
    { "name": "Error 01", "desc_1": "Test: 01", "desc_2": "Testing" },
    { "name": "Error 03", "desc_1": "Test: 03", "desc_2": "Testing" }],
}, {
  "errorname": [
    { "name": "Error 02", "desc_1": "Test: 02", "desc_2": "Testing" },
    { "name": "Error 09", "desc_1": "Test: 09", "desc_2": "Testing" }
  ]
}];

var errorMap = b.reduce(function(outer, group) {
  return group.errorname.reduce(function(inner, item) {
    return inner.set(item.name, {
      desc_1: item.desc_1,
      desc_2: item.desc_2
    });
  }, outer);
}, new Map);

console.log(Object.fromEntries([...errorMap]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```